# Convert array and tuple elements to columns in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this (sample with two rows):

```
    cadd_scores_vec        freqs_vec     CLASS
0  [0.001, -4.053424]  (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)      0
1  [0.001, -3.654581]  (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)      0
```

and I need to de-struct all the content, to single scalar columns, like this:

```
   col1   col2       col3 col4 col5 col6
0  0.001  -4.053424  0.0  0.0  0.0  0
1  0.001  -3.654581  0.0  0.0  0.0  0
```

I don't care too much about the new column names; the important thing is to arrange rows into plain vectors as shown above.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to do this with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.tolist()) for col in df.columns], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

or

```
pd.concat([df[col].apply(pd.Series) for col in df.columns], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

`ignore_index=True` just makes sure you don't get duplicated column names.